# Validation errors for LLMChain when use langchain/openai for text generation

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, py-langchain

I just started learning langchain.  I was trying to use langchain and openai for text generation. Codes below. (I use python 3.10):

```
#openai==1.3.5
#langchain==0.0.345

from transformers import pipeline
from langchain import PromptTemplate, LLMChain, OpenAI

import os
os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = '*****'

def generate_story (scenario):
  template = ''' 
          You are a story teller. Please make a story based on the context below:
          CONTEXT: {scenario}
          STORY: 
  '''

  prompt = PromptTemplate (template = template, input_variables = ['scenario'])
  story_llm = LLMChain(LLM = OpenAI(
       model_name = 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
       temperature = 1),
        prompt = prompt
  )
  story = story_llm.predict(scenario = scenario)
  print(story)
  return story


scenario = 'A person is skiing down a snowy slope.'
story = generate_story (scenario)
print(story)
```

However, I got errors like below:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pydantic/main.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__()

ValidationError: 2 validation errors for LLMChain
llm
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
LLM
  extra fields not permitted (type=value_error.extra)
```

Spent hours trying to find out why but could not figure that out. Does anyone know what went wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Python arguments are case sensitive (unless made otherwise). lower case the keyword to your keyword argument:

`LLMChain(llm = OpenAI(`
`----------↑-----------`

Your keyword to `LLMChain` is uppercase when it should be lower case

Comment: thanks. That was a dumb error. Now I got message like:  You tried to access openai.ChatCompletion, but this is no longer supported in openai>=1.0.0 - see the README at https://github.com/openai/openai-python for the API.....  Looks like it's not supporting new version of openai.   Is langchain supporting openai>1.0.0?  if so, how I should  modify the code to make it work?